# preg_replace specific src attribute in input tag

Tags: php, paypal, attributes, preg-replace

I have a PayPal button code for which I want to use my own image. Here is the PayPal button code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="Q8LQ82SNNSBKC"> 
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/images/pp-buy-now-btn-bryellow.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!"> 
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"> 
</form>
```

...which contains several 'input' tags, and I want to replace the 'src' for the input (type of image). I have created my best effort of code to do this:

```
$paypal_button_code2 = preg_replace('/<input[type="image"]\ [^>]+src="([^"]+)"/', $newimageurl, $paypal_button_code);
```

but this is not working.

Can someone please point me in the right direction (either with correct code, or a help page for working through regex the easy way!!)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go with html is DOMDocument, not regex:

```
$html = '<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top"> <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"> <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="Q8LQ82SNNSBKC"> <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/images/pp-buy-now-btn-bryellow.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!"> <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"> </form>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<div id="root">' . $html . '</div>');
$root = $dom->getElementById('root');
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodeList = $xp->query('//form[@action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"][1]/input[@type="image"]/@src');

if ( $nodeList ) {
    $newimageurl = 'path/to/newimage.gif';
    $nodeList->item(0)->nodeValue = $newimageurl;
    $html = '';

    foreach ($root->childNodes as $childNode) {
        $html .= $dom->saveHTML($childNode);
    }
}

echo $html;
```

XPath query details:

```
//    # anywhere in the DOM tree
form  # a form element
[     # open a predicate (condition on the current element)
    # must have an attribute "action" with the value of this string
    @action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
]
[1] # other predicate: first occurrence of this kind of form
/   # direct child
input
[
    @type="image"
]
/
@src # src attribute
```

About `'<div id="root">' . $html . '</div>'`:

`DOMDocument::loadHTML` loads an html string and builds the DOM tree. To do that you need a root element, but since you are dealing with html parts and not a whole html document, it's possible that your string isn't enclosed between a unique element (that is `<html>...</html>` in a whole html document). To avoid automatic corrections from DOMDocument, the trick consists to provide a fake root element. Once the DOM tree edited, all you have to do is to concatenate all the children of the root element.

Comment: Thanks - this worked perfectly... it's currently way over my head technically (which was why I was hoping to sort it using preg_replace or something similar), so it won't be something I'll be able to re-use to easily (!!)  Cheers :)

Comment: @AndyiBM: Using DOMDocument isn't difficult, there are sometimes 2 or 3 things a bit strange you need to know and that's all. It's well documented in the PHP manual (comments are useful too). A little more difficult is the XPath language that requires a dedicated tutorial (see http://www.zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html). I will add more details to my answer.

Comment: @AndyiBM: other advantage, learning how to use the DOM isn't only useful for PHP. Once you know it, you can use it in all languages that have an implementation of libxml (pretty near all languages and many tools).

Comment: This is awesome, @Casimir et Hippolyte - I really appreciate the extra homework you've done here. I didn't know any of this...

Answer (score 1):

you dont need `<input[type="image"]`

```
$paypal_button_code2 = preg_replace('/src="([^"]+)/', 'src="'.$newimageurl, $paypal_button_code, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks - this works, but it also changes the second 'src' attribute which I need to leave as it is. This was why I specified the 'src' as part of the input[type="image"]

Comment: you just need to add `, 1);` to limit replace for first one, see updated answer. `input[type="image"]` it used for css or javascript selector what you want is `input type="image"`

Comment: Ah - yes, thanks @ewwink, that does work perfectly now... I need to check whether the  order will always remain the same for PayPal button code (in case their pixel.gif image gets moved at any point)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
<input type="image" src="<?php echo $newimageurl;?>" ...>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is task will be done by a non-tech person, and I wanted to automate it by allowing them to select an image file, and have it swap in without them editing HTML

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to not work on your HTML like you are doing. This is really the wrong way to go.

I recommend that you either use a template framework, a simple one such as smarty - https://www.smarty.net/ - or at least that you format your string such as:

```php
$my_url = "http://whatyouwant";
$whatever_html = <<<EOT
<input type="image" src={%MYCOOKIE%} border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!"> <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"> </form>
EOT;

$whatever_html = str_replace($whatever_html, $my_url, "{%MYCOOKIE%}");
```

The special syntax with triple '<<<' (HEREDOC) allows you to put any kind of HTML code without having to further be wary of quotes.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Thanks - this might be something for me to look at another time.